# Is there any significance to the Angels' wing colours?

Tags: character, analysis, lucifer

In the TV-series [Lucifer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer_(TV_series)), Lucifer used to have wings and they are later revealed to be of bright white colour. But his brother had blackish wings. Is it due to his skin colour or is there any significance to it? Is there any explanation of it in comics or is it based on some Catholic beliefs?

Comment: Lucifer doesn't borrow heavily from the comics. Comic Amenadiel is white with white wings and nothing like the Show Amenadiel.

Comment: @cde I know nothing from comics

Comment: Yes, hence the comment letting you know that it doesn't borrow much from the comics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of Amenadiel being black, Uriel and Lucifer's wings are white as his skin too.

As you can see they are white:

[image: Lucifer Wings]

And Uriel are white too, with a bit of brown but it can be shadows illusion:

[image: Uriel Wings]

We don't have proofs until now, so it's a big probability of being by skin colour. Perhaps, I have another suggestion that's because of Amenadiel being a warrior and Uriel and Lucifer don't.

Comment: By that logic my wings will be pale yellow if I become angel  ;D

Comment: Yeah probably if you are asian ;D Nice touch of humor fella!

Comment: I don’t think skin color has anything to do with it. It is more than likely a factor of status or job roles. As you have stated, Amenadiel is a warrior of the heavenly host. Where as Lucifer has been described as the angel of light or “The Bright One”. He is also called “the light bringer”, “The Shining One”, or the bringer of the dawn. He is “The Morning Star”. Ureil, on the other hand, has neither one of those distinctions.

Comment: This cannot be correct because Michael who's the twin of Lucifer (means he's white too) has dark wings and Azrael (Angel of Death) who's Asian has white wings.

Answer (score 3):

At the very beginning of season 5 (and even in the trailer of this 5 season), we learn that:

> Lucifer has a twin brother who looks exactly like him and (likely) share the exact same DNA.

However, those two angels have very different wings colors even though they share the same skin color.

We also know from season 3 that:

> Angels "self-actualize" and have control over there own wings and own power. Thus, they are the only one responsible if they:
>
>  - Lose their powers
>  - Get their powers back
>  - Lose their wings
>  - Get their wings back

Given that, I believe it is safe to assume that each angel actually **choose** the color of their wings and have control over it (so they could *probably* change the color of their own wings if they wanted to).

Since angels choose which color their wings are, it probably has a meaning but only for themself. So two angels with the same wings color could have two different meanings.

Maybe one has white wings because it goes well with their skin color and the other has white wings because it represents purity to them.

Comment: *Given that, I believe it is safe to assume that each angel actually choose the color of their wings*, well except Lucifer in S04 when he discovered the kind of wings that he got back...

Comment: @WoJ It's an inconscient choice that reflects how he sees himself, not conscient one

Comment: I don't think so, because that it's God's choice

Answer (score -2):

I suppose it's skin colour. For the comics, amenediel is White, with long Gray hair and White wings. I suppose the show is trying to be racially equal

Comment: This seem more like speculation than verifiable answer. I suggest taking the [Tour](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about good answers. Plus, you'll get your first badge.